# Extensions Real World Examples?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extensions

I am an undergrad currently studying GIS. I'm working on a paper and I need real world examples of the ArcGIS Extensions i.e. how have people used them. I need to find articles online but so far haven't had much luck. There are plenty of tutorials though.
I need at least one example article for each extension. I was hoping that someone here could point me in the right direction.

Any links to websites or articles where I could find projects that people have done with extensions?

I need examples of the official ArcGIS extensions. Namely: ArcGIS 3D Analyst, ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst, ArcGIS Network Analyst, ArcGIS Schematics, ArcGIS Spatial Analyst, and ArcGIS Tracking Analyst.

Comment: I would guess that your difficulty in finding relevant articles stems from most companies choosing not to share which softwares they use to arrive at a given solution. It may be more helpful to search for articles that have solutions that could be replicated or extended in ArcGIS extensions.

Comment: Here is a number of case studies that might be of interest:http://www.esri.com/industries/water_resources/user_showcase/case_studies.html#flood

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of seeming redundant, I think you will be hard pressed to find a website/article that states "We used X extension for this!" I am betting your best results will be looking into scholarly journals and articles that are essentially required to spill the beans on what analysis tools they made use of.

Examples:
[Interpolating Surfaces in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst](http://webapps.fundp.ac.be/geotp/SIG/interpolating.pdf)  - Spatial Analyst

[Application of ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst for Interpolating Environmental Data from Observations](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ep.10223/full)  - Geostastitical Analyst

[Using GIS to Analyze Animal Movements in the Marine Environment](http://alaska.usgs.gov/science/biology/spatial/gistools/anim_mov_useme.pdf) - Tracking Analyst

Just a few results from making use of Google's Scholar search.

Answer (score 3):

As linked by Raj the website does provide customer success stories. just a little digging from his link provides [customer success stories](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/3danalyst/success-stories.html).
Many  of those are published in the hardcopy and online publications by esri [arcnews](http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/index.html), [arcuser](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/index.html), and [arcwatch](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/index.html).
Just search each pub by extension name.
Also there are many industry rags published by ESRI which have extension specific stories.
Find some of those on the [subscription page](http://www.esri.com/publications/apps/newsletters/pub_form.cfm)

Comment: I agree.  There are many, many articles published in arcnews & arcuser that talk about the success stories of Arc extensions.  If you read through the back articles, you should have no trouble finding what you need.